# Newsletter subscription page should provide a link to a preview of newsletter

Tags: feature-request, newsletter

When viewing the list of newsletters you've subscribed to you should be able to click either the newsletter title, publish date, or new link entirely to see a preview of that newsletter. Picture below because they are worth 1,000 words:

[image]